Extract column from excel table without rows with NA
I want to create in excel a new table from a large data set and only include individuals that have a weight. I don't want to use the normal filter option from the ribbon.

your text
=FILTER(data[id], id[weight]<> 0)  

your text
=FILTER(data[id], is.number(data[weight]))  

your text
=VLOOKUP(1,CHOOSE({1,2},data[weight]>0,data[id]),2,0)  

all these options returned #N/A

Try =FILTER(data,data[weight]<>"NA","").

Or =FILTER(data,ISNUMBER(data[weight]),"") just in case there are other non-numerics there.

You can use Power Query to remove rows according to your criteria and load results to a new location.
